# d3.js margin values echoed from PHP don't work

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I echo margins for my graph from PHP(Laravel) into JavaScript like this:

```
margin = { 
    top: {!! $margins !!}[ 0 ],
    bottom: {!! $margins !!}[ 1 ], 
    left: {!! $margins !!}[ 2 ],
    right: {!! $margins !!}[ 3 ]
},
```

`$margins` is an array which has many values. `Console.log( {!! $margins !!}[ 0 ] )` returns a correct value for margin, which is `30`. When I look at the source though, I see:

```
margin = { 
    top: ["30","30","50","20","30","30","50","20"][ 0 ],
    bottom: ["30","30","50","20","30","30","50","20"][ 1 ], 
    left: ["30","30","50","20","30","30","50","20"][ 2 ],
    right: ["30","30","50","20","30","30","50","20"][ 3 ]
},
```

The problem is that d3 seems to sum up all the margin values in the array. I.e. instead of 30, it returns 30+30+50+20+30+30+50+20 = 260.

Does anyone know why it does it and how I can fix it?

---

EDIT: I had it a bit wrong. It doesn't sum up the array values, it edits SVG height instead when I set margins from JSON array.

Answer (score -1):

There might be a bug. As of d3.js 4.9.1, it is still there. Top and bottom margins must be forced into numeric data types, otherwise they take JSON string as an input. Left and right margins are automatically converted into integers. So this works:

```
margin = { 
    top: {!! $margins !!}[ 0 ] * 1,
    bottom: {!! $margins !!}[ 1 ] * 1, 
    left: {!! $margins !!}[ 2 ],
    right: {!! $margins !!}[ 3 ]
},
```